# How to route 404s to a specific page in Ghost(Pro)?

Tags: yaml, http-status-code-404, ghost-blog, custom-error-pages

I'm interested in routing all 404 redirects to a specific page in my Ghost(Pro) blog. How do I do this? If it's with YAML, what do I put in the routes.yaml to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I didn't do enough of a deep dive for the info. Ghost has [automatic routing of error pages](https://ghost.org/docs/themes/contexts/error/) via the error.hbs, error-404.hbs, and error-500.hbs template files.